# Fibonacci me da números negativos

Tags: java, fibonacci

Tengo una pequeña duda con mi código para realizar mi programa de Fibonacci ya que al momento de imprimir los valores me da el numero pero en negativo.

```
class doWhileTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int primertermino = -1;
        int segundotermino = 1;
        int incremento = 0;

        do{
            int fibo = primertermino + segundotermino;
            segundotermino = primertermino;
            primertermino = fibo;
            System.out.println(+fibo);
            incremento++;
        }
        while(incremento < 100);

        System.out.println("Se acabo");

    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes que invertir los valores iniciales, asi : **primertermino = 1** y **segundotermino = -1** y Bienvenido a StackoverflowEs !!! ,

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El algoritmo que haces esta algo mal, intenta con esto:

```
class doWhileTest{ 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
int f1=0,f2=-1,f3=1;
int incremento = 0;
    do{
        f1 = f2 + f3;
        f2 = f3;
        f3= f1;
        System.out.println(f1);
        incremento++;
    }while(incremento < 100);
    System.out.println("Se acabo");
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que tu error es declarar a en cada siclo nuevo a `int fibo`, lo cual puede provocar el error que indicas, ademas de que el algoritmo esta mal al hacer :

> segundotermino = primertermino;
>   primertermino = fibo;

deberias de hacer:

> primertermino=segundotermino;
>   segundotermino = fibo;

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás declarando variables tipo INT y estás solo admiten hasta un cierto limite, probando con una variable tipo LONG te dé una mayor capacidad de números (Cabe recalcar que en la sucesión de fibonacci se llegan a números muy elevados). Te dejo un algoritmo que cree a modo de explicación visual

```
class doWhileTest
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  long x=1,y=0,suma=0,i=0;
  System.out.println(x);
  do
  {
   suma = x+y;
   System.out.println(suma);
   y=x;
   x=suma;
   i++;
  }while(i<100);
  System.out.println("Se acabo.");
 }
}`**
```